# How do you detect all child components of a given route have rendered in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm looking to run a function after all the child components of a route/url have rendered for a Vue front end.  `Vue.nextTick` only seems to run once when there's a refresh and since I am not changing data in the root Vue instances, it won't fire again.  I don't have access to Vue Router since the routing is being handled by a back end CMS.  Is there a way to detect that the Vue root instance having child components that are changing and that when they are finished rendering, I can run my function?  The `updated` lifecycle hook also doesn't seem to be an options because, again, data on the root instance doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question I think you could send an event to the root instance from the child whenever the `updated` hook is called in the child.

Example:

Child:

```
<div>Hello</div>
<script>
export default {
 updated: {
   this.$emit("render")
 }
}
</script>
```

Root:

```
<child v-on:render="onChildRender">
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onChildRender() {
      console.log("child rendered")
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Hopefully, this helps.